# Get point on arc for path follower

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

**I am trying to create a simple path system with C# in Unity.**

So far, everything works perfectly. But to create a path follower, I need the position to which the follower should move every frame. The paths always have a radius, a starting point and a length, the rest is unknown.

Now, **how do I calculate** the position of the path follower in each frame, i.e. **point on the arc**? I need a function that takes as argument the percentage position of the follower on the path and that returns a global position in the scene.
Here is an example: the length of the arc L, the radius r and the starting point A are given. What I am trying to calculate is the random point D:
[image: Description of problem]

The point that I calculate on my own is just a mess and doesn't work, even though I've already done some research. So I am looking for a simple and understandable solution.

Comment: Impossible with only a radius, starting point and length, since that does not describe a single specific arc. You would also need the center point for the corresponding circle.

Comment: @JonasH But we could calculate the point B in this case with the starting point and the radius, right? **B = (5|0)**

Comment: @jjb So B.Y coordinate is given, isn't it?

Comment: @MBo When calculated, yes.

Comment: Only with an additional constraint about the relation from the start point to the center. If you want to allow arbitrary arcs you cannot have such a constraint.

Comment: Also. It is fairly common to use splines to approximate arcs, with an error of ~0.03% it should be good enough for computer graphics. Implementing a cubic spline is more work, but also much more general.

Comment: @JonasH Could you explain roughly how this works or what the main idea behind splines is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the length of the arc L, the radius r and the starting point A are given

- A circles circumference is defined by `2 * r * pi`. A whole circumference, calculated using `r=5`: `fullCircumference = 31.4159265359`.
- A partical circumference (the *arc*) is given by `L`, we know it's `L/fullCircumference` gives `0.21263598811` which is the fraction that L takes from the whole circumference.
- We can convert the arc fraction to radians, given that a whole circle has `2PI` -> `0.21263598811 * 2 * PI = 1.33603131627 rad`
- Now to the **Starting Point A**. I assume it's always ON the arc somewhere.
  Though, if we start with sin(0) and cos(0) we are at "12 o Clock":
  [image]
  So we need to calculate the offset in radians around the circle.
- Though you didn't give us `B` and I can't assume that though the radius alone.  So I will just ignore this for now and offset the forumla by 90° (or half pi) to get to `A`
- D's x & y would then be defined by: `D(sin(x - pi/2) * r, cos(x - pi/2)) * r;`
- And if we enter the 1.336 rad we calculated, it looks about right:
  [image]

The c# code would look like this (didn't compile though):

```
 Vector2 pointOnCircle(float L, float r){
    
    float fullCircumference = 2f * Mathf.PI * r;
    float partialCircumference = L / fullCircumference;
    float arcRadians = partialCircumference * 2f * Mathf.PI;

    float circularOffset = Mathf.PI / 2f;
    Vector2 D = new Vector2();
    D.x = Mathf.Sin(arcRadians - circularOffset) * r;
    D.y = Mathf.Cos(arcRadians - circularOffset) * r;

    return D;
}
```

- So we got `C`, now you want a random point D between A and C on that arc.
- We now need to sample a point on the arc using a fraction between 0 and 1 (0 being at A, 1 being at C):
- The arc's length is `arcRadians` in radians, so we can just mutiply that with `0..1`:

code:

```
Vector2 pointOnArc(float L, float r, float fraction){ // fraction is between 0 and 1
    
    float fullCircumference = 2f * Mathf.PI * r;
    float partialCircumference = L / fullCircumference;
    float arcRadians = partialCircumference * 2f * Mathf.PI;

    float circularOffset = Mathf.PI / 2f;
    Vector2 D = new Vector2();
    D.x = Mathf.Sin(fraction * arcRadians - circularOffset) * r;
    D.y = Mathf.Cos(fraction * arcRadians - circularOffset) * r;

    return D;
}
```

And there you go:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, math genius! I added another if statement which checks if the path has a radius with value zero. Also, I had a problem with D.x, because the position was shifted, you still have to add the radius, then everything works perfectly. Many, many thanks!

Comment: Yes, my circle is centered around 0,0 - you can shift it to match B easily. Depending on the freedom of `A` it could get a bit more complex though.

Answer (score 1):

Percentage is between 0 and 1 and length is the arc length. You can remove center to center on 0, 0 or you can offset center so the point starts where you want.

Make radius negative if you want it on the other side. Make arc length negative if you want it to go the other way.

End is the angle from the start of the arc to the end of the arc.
Angle is the end multiplied by percentage. Then turn polar coordinates (angle and radius) to cartesian coordinates (x, y) and offset that by center.

```
Vector2 getPoint(Vector2 center, float length, float radius, float percentage)
{
    float end = length / radius;
    float angle = end * percentage;

    float x = center.x + (Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius);
    float y = center.y + (Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius);

    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```